# SharePoint 2013 REST API: Modify File Fields

Tags: 2013, development, rest, json

I am trying to update the fields of a just uploaded SharePoint document.

To upload the file, I POST to the following endpoint:

```
"_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/{0}DropOffLibrary')/Files/add(url='{1}',overwrite=true)"
```

I then GET the file after uploading is complete:

```
"_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/dodrc/DropOffLibrary/{0}')/ListItemAllFields", fileName
```

Where I'm struggling is in updating the fields of the uploaded file.

```
"_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/dodrc/DropOffLibrary/" + fileName + "')"
```

I have tried to MERGE a slightly modified JSON object, and a SharePoint file model (with updated fields), but I keep receiving bad request (400) error messages.

I have also attempted to Google my question, but I'm not finding much in the way of useful results.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For updating you can do a `POST` request to `/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('fileurl')/ListItemAllFields`

The body should be something like

```
body: { '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Data.DocumentsItem' }, 'FieldName': 'FieldValue' }
```

Along with header `X-HTTP-Method: MERGE`

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/76583/rest-post-with-metadata-column