# Trying to upload files using REST

Tags: sharepoint-server, rest, sharepoint-rest-api

I'm using the following method to write to a SharePoint list using REST with data from a HTML form. How can I modify it to also be able to also upload a files from the form? Thank you.

```
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "https://.../_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('SupportTracker')/items",
            method: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify({
                '__metadata' : {'type': 'SP.Data.SupportTrackerListItem'},
                'Title': title,
                'Network': network,
                'Enclave': enclave,
                'Application': application,
                'User_x0020_Account': sysuseracct,
                'POC_x0020_Name': pocname,
                'Problem_x0020_Type': problemtype,
                'DTGStart': dateissuebegan,
                'Details': details,
                'POC_x0020_Phone_x0020_Number': pocnumber,
                'POCEmailAddress2': pocemail,
                'AssignedTo': assignedto,
                'Ticket_x0020_number': externaltt

            }),
            headers: {
                "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "X-RequestDigest": formdigest
            },
            success: function(data) {
                console.log("entry created successfully...");
            },
            error: function(data) {
                //console.log("#__REQUESTDIGEST".val());
                console.log("Error message: " + JSON.stringify(data.responseJSON.error));
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

NO,you can't upload file and set column value in one request.
Similar issue for your reference:
[REST post with metadata column?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/76583/rest-post-with-metadata-column)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45175323/sharepoint-2013-online-can-i-set-other-column-values-when-uploading-a-file-using